# How can I make a hidden <td> row while creating html table from json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a json data in a format like this:

```
'[{"number":"1","id":"2","price":"100.70","date":"2015-10-18 03:00:00","hidden":"21"},
{"number":"2","id":"2","price":"88.20","date":"2015-10-18 04:00:00","hidden":"22"}]';
```

I'm receiving this data and later on I'm creating a table content from it:

```
json = JSON.parse(data);

$.each(json, function(i, v) {
  $('<tr/>', {
    html: [$('<td/>', {
      text: v.number
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.id
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.price
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.date
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: 'show details'
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.hidden
    })]
  }).appendTo('#dataTables-example tbody')
})
```

and it appends nicely to my existing html code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>number</th>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>price</th>
          <th>date</th>
            <th>show details</th>
          <th style="display:none;">hidden identifier</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

In every row I have a field 'show details'. In my json I'm passing the `hidden` parameter and when user clicks the 'show details' link it should show him just an alert window with a number from `hidden` field. I don't want to show the value to user in the table, but all I can do so far is to hide this field in a header:

```
<th style="display:none;">hidden identifier</th>
```

But how can I hid it in every row, but also pass it to the alert when user clicks `show details`?

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uo8rc5qL/1/

Thanks!

Comment: use a `data-` attribute on the row

Comment: My solution: http://jsfiddle.net/uo8rc5qL/2/

Comment: Thanks @Rsauxil - but is there a way of alerting the hidden data instead of showing it next to the link?

Comment: There are plenty, here I used bootstrap dialog as an example, http://jsfiddle.net/uo8rc5qL/5/ (note that using javascripts built in alert function is perceived as spammy a lot of the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you also have js to handle the click of show details, right?
If that's the case you can just add the `hidden` in a `data` attribute and then retrieve it in the click handle.

Something like:

```
$.each(json, function(i, v) {
  $('<tr/>', {
    html: [$('<td/>', {
      text: v.number
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.id
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.price
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.date
    }), $('<td/>', {
      html: [
        $('<a/>', {
          href: '#',
          class: 'show-details',
          text: 'show details',
          data: { id: v.hidden },
          click: function() {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            console.log(id);
            alert(id);
          }
        })
      ]
    })]
  }).appendTo('#dataTables-example tbody')
})
```

Then on the click handle:

```
$('.show-details').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  // whatever you have here.
})
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution, but when I put `$('<td class="show-details"/>',` then the fields are empty, but when I remove the class attribute and leave `$('<td/>',` then it shows me the text show details, which is not a hyperlink at that point.. What can be the issue here?

Comment: Sorry about that, just typed it w/o testing. It is working now, I also added the hyperlink inside the div and used the class in the `<a/>` instead of the `td`. Hope that works.

Comment: thanks for the quick respond :) Now everything displays correctly, but when I added alert here: `$('.show-details').on('click', function() {
 var id = $(this).data('id');
 alert(id);
})` it doesn't show after I click the link, do you know what might be the case?

Comment: Ha, that's weird, I tested and worked for me. Do you have the click binding on the document ready callback? Maybe try my last edit.

Comment: Ok, your last edit did the trick, I know it looks like a workaround, but I have no idea why the previous version didn't work for me :(

Comment: You are right, it didn't work for me if I put the binding outside of the document ready. Maybe this helps `$(function() { $('.show-details').on('click', function() { //same code here }) })`?

Comment: Just a guess. It is hard to tell w/o seeing the surrounding code.

Comment: yeah, seems like I'll have to live with a workaround, the normal solution didn't work on my environment (which is weird since it works on jsfiddle), but yeah, what can you do ;) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help. In my opinion, the last version is better since it doesn't even need the class attribute, looks more idiomatic to me so don't let the workaround keep up at night ;-)

Answer (score 0):

just add click event and handle the show/hide there:

```
    var data = '[{"number":"1","id":"2","price":"100.70","date":"2015-10-18 03:00:00","hidden":"21"},{"number":"2","id":"2","price":"88.20","date":"2015-10-18 04:00:00","hidden":"22"}]';

json = JSON.parse(data);

$.each(json, function(i, v) {
  $('<tr/>', {
    html: [$('<td/>', {
      text: v.number
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.id
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.price
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: v.date
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: 'show details'
    }), $('<td><div style="display:none;">'+ v.hidden+'</div><a class="hidden">show hidden</a></td>')]
  }).appendTo('#dataTables-example tbody')
});

$(".hidden").bind("click",function(){
   alert($(this).parent().children().first().html()); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uo8rc5qL/4/

Comment: thanks, but it's not exactly what I want... I want to have the hyperlink attached to the words "show details" and when user clikcs it - it will alert the hidden value... Could you help me with that?